# MS Office 2013 Can not install again

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-office-2013

I'm having issues installing Office 2013.

When I try to install it, I get the error message

> ...setup.exe has stopped working

This I is how my trouble started:

1. In order to install Office 2013, I used Revo Uninstaller to uninstall Office 2010
2. Revo Uninstaller has warned me at some points as it wrote that "be careful, these registiries are common in more than 1 office program"
3. unfortunately I didn't give importance and deleted everything it listed
4. I installed Office 2013 then, activated also with no problem
5. But I still got Office 2010 updates despite I uninstalled it
6. Then I uninstalled 2013 and decided to clean all leftovers
7. I used CCleaner also made some manual deletions from regedit (again unfortunately)
   NOW, I can't install office 2013. It says that office 2013 setup.exe has stopped working.

I also didn't have a regedit backup.

I tried lots of things from lots of pages. Official fix-it softwares didn't worked for me.

I also tried to install Office 2010 and then 2013. But in this case:

1. I could install 2010 but couldn't activated it again
2. Again I couldn't install 2013, it gave same fault message: "office 2013 setup.exe has stopped working"

I used CCleaner and some more similar software to clean my registries. Those didn't help also.

I only have problem with office. I don't want to format my computer since the fault is with MS Office 2013, the rest of the machine is working fine.

I am asking you guys that what should I do to be sure that after those actions all office files, registries, everything related with office are deleted so my computer is like formatted (by means of Office)

Comment: Can you explain what is actually wrong? Do you get any error message? Is the fault only with MS Office?

Comment: Hi Dave, I can't install Office 2013. No special error message. Only message is setup.exe has stopped working. yes, fault is only with MS Office. The other softwares and OS in my computer is very healthy.

Comment: I would install CCleaner and run the registry clearner - it will do a cleanup and may fix this. When it crashes, can you see if the event log shows any extra detail?

Comment: Please provide the installation log it would contain the error code.  Why didn't you just install Office 2013 and Office 2010 at the same time?  Furthermore Office 2010 can be uninstalled through Add/Remove Programs.

Comment: I used CCleaner and some more similar software. Those didn't help. But may be event log will solve all my trouble. Where I can find it on my computer Dave? Let me look for it, so I can ask a more narrowed question.

Comment: Event viewer details http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308427

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

1. Reinstall Office 2010
2. Install Office 2013

The 2013 installer will ask you if you want to remove 2010

Comment: I am sorry that I forgot to mention this. I tried the method you wrote. Office 2010 works but can not be activated. Office 2013 still has same fault message and can not be installed. Noe I -'ll edit my question to add this info. Sorry again.